# Work VPN Keeps dropping

Tags: vpn

Our work VPN connection is dropping intermittently.  Sometimes it'll go 20x a day, other times weeks will pass by and no loss of connectivity. Apparently the cause of this is outlined below:

> "Your L2TP client uses your internal address to create a unique tunnel ID. As so many users are using the 192.168.1.x subnet at home duplicated tunnel IDs are created and this causes the problem.
>
> To rectity, you can change this to any internal subnet you like – 192.168.2.X for example."

We've been asked to change settings on our home routers to facilitate the VPN.  Does this sound reasonable/usual or is the VPN just a bit rubbish? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the usual problem with VPN. They are used to establish a tunnel between two networks (your home network, and your work network) which were formerly separated. If both used "private addresses" (e.g. the addresses in 192.168.*.* addresses, which were meant for that), collisions may happen, which will imply dysfunctions: when two distinct machines on a given network use the same IP, things tend to break.

If both networks are to be linked together, then they must agree on which addresses they may or may not use, so as to avoid collisions. From the point of view of your work sysadmin, *you* are the one who should change his IP addresses.

(This is not a security issue, rather an allocation issue.)

Comment: It's not the answer I wanted, but I understand :)

Comment: How can it not be the answer you wanted?  You asked if it was reasonable and its very reasonable since it takes 30 seconds to change your home network's configuration.